# Access vba Replace/Regex?

Tags: regex, database, vba

Afternoon,

I'm having trouble with some data imports from PowerPoint into Access.

Initially when I import the data the notes section comes in as the below for each row:

```
 <div class="ExternalClass63DBAC931E7D4E4680E207BF938770AA"><p>xxxxxxxxxxx.</p> <p>xxxxxxxxxxxx</p></div>
```

The xxxxxxx is where the data I want to pull out is.
I have tried Regex in the form of replacing everything between the <> as seen below

```
Public Function AddPipesBeforeDates(ByVal strText As String) As String
Dim regex As Object
Dim matches As Object
Dim m As Object


Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regex.Global = True
regex.pattern = "<.*>"
Set matches = regex.Execute(strText)
For Each m In matches
    strText = Replace(strText, m, "")
Next
AddPipesBeforeDates = strText

Set matches = Nothing
Set regex = Nothing
End Function
```

The problem becomes it wipes out everything.
I just found out about Regex and I'm not familiar with it.
Is there a way to delete the unwanted data?

Note the xxxxxx data can be any value spaces or special characters

Any thoughts or ideas on how to do this would be appreciated.  I may be going at this the wrong way.

Thanks

Comment: Use `<[^>]*>` or `<[^<>]*>` regex to remove only between `<...>`.

Comment: Thank you very much that works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must note that `.` matches any character but a newline (thus, including `<` and `>`).

To remove all substrings between `<` and `>`, you may use

```
regex.pattern = "<[^<]+>"
```

This way, you will avoid "overfiring" and matching more than you need.